# Symfony 2: Communicating with another Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

We have our own framework based on `Symfony 2.4`, it's basically a Symfony2 project (several bundles). For one project we need a webshop, for which we have chosen `Sylius`. Because our own project and `Sylius` have a few dependencies in common with **different** versions, we cannot have them function in one project together. I've tried to make this work but the errors and mismatches were endless, in addition `Sylius` uses `Symfony 2.3` (*this isn't the bottleneck as it can be upgraded to 2.4*).

Now we have chosen to host `Sylius` as a standalone project with a shared database over the both projects. The Sylius installation resides in the `/web/shop/` directory and functions fine when browsing to `http://example.com/shop/`. We want to be able to have these two projects communicate with each other, it would be nice if we can call some of Sylius' services from within our own framework and vice versa.

I've tried instantiating the `AppKernel` of our own framework within Sylius by using `require_once` in a service, but all of my attempts have failed, seeing as you cannot `require_once` in class with a namespace.

How would I go about getting this done?

This is an invalid service I've tried to implement which yielded a `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot mix bracketed namespace declarations with unbracketed namespace declarations` exception:

```
namespace Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle;    
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

class MyFrameworkBridge {

    private $framework;

    public function __construct(Kernel $kernel) {
        $root = $kernel->getRootDir();
        $ownFrameworkDir = $root.'/../../../../source/app';

        require_once $ownFrameworkDir.'/bootstrap.php.cache';
        require_once $ownFrameworkDir.'/AppKernel.php';

        $this->framework = new AppKernel('dev'); // never reaches this line
    }

}
```

Comment: You would be better off just creating API calls on each of them and using those rather than trying to load the entire application into the other application.

Comment: Chausser, thank you for your answer. I will experiment with this today. Maybe you could write an answer, if it works I'll accept it.

Comment: Have you tried registering one project's bundles into the other? Also, something like inheriting one Kernel from the other and calling `$bundles = array_merge(parent::registerBundles(), ...)` could work.